# execute if, if window.location contains two strings and a specified variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I am using this javascript

```
<script>
var windowloc = window.location;
var pink ="http://my.blogspot.com/search/label/Pink%20Template";
var blue ="http://my.blogspot.com/search/label/blue%20Template";
var yellow ="http://my.blogspot.com/search/label/yellow%20Template";
if((windowloc==pink)||(windowloc==blue)||(windowloc==yellow)){
//execute JavaScript
}
</script>
```

there are many more `variables` and I would much prefer it if the `JS if` was something along the lines where `"+colorss+"` can be an array of specified possibilities, I have tried the below
**EDIT** it must contain `http://my.blogspot.com/search/label/` THEN a specified variable and then `%20Template`.

```
<script>
var windowloc = window.location;
var colorss = "'Pink'||'yellow'||'blue'";
if(windowloc=='http://my.blogspot.com/search/label/'+colorss+'%20Template'){
//execute JavaScript
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
if(/(pink|yellow|blue)/.test(window.location)) {
    // do something
}
```

Or if you want to match the whole URL:

```
if(/my\.blogspot\.com\/search\/label\/(pink|yellow|blue)%20Template$/.test(window.location)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: sorry i gave a wrong url it was meant to be my(DOT)blogspot so my.blogspot.com/search....etc

Comment: Thankyou I will accept your answer as soon as i am allowed, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Although doing it with regular expressions would work fine, this is an alternative:

```
var windowloc = window.location;
var colors = ['Pink','Yellow','Blue'];
for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    var colorss = colors[i];
    if(windowloc=='http://my.blogspot.com/search/label/'+colorss+'%20Template'){
        //execute JavaScript
    }
}
```

Simple loops are all that is neccessary for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

suppose, you want to have specific code for set of URLs which doesn't have a pattern or more than manageable URLs with specific pattern(like 100 different colors).

Have a element 'spl_code' field in a page and write following code in JS layer

```
if(document.getElementById('spl_code')) {
    // write code
}
```